# In Oracle Sql Developer, how can I view package_b scope (static) variables while debuging package_a?

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

I'm trying the debug function in Oracle Sql Developer 18.4, it looks fine until I ran into some complicate cases, one of them is, it seems I cannot view package_b.some_variable while I'm inside package_a.

[image: pk_DatVerify.somevariable display as ? while I break in pk_UtlVerify]

See above screen, I'm currently break in package_a, which populate data into package_b (pk_DatVerify.g_model_boc and pk_DatVerify.g_model_boc_count), but the "Watches" window is not able to display any of them.

Is there any way I can see the variable value in pk_DatVerify.g_model_boc at that moment? Even if I have to manually type "dbms_output.put_line" somewhere (like in a command window), it will be much helpful!

Comment: I find the "Execute SQL in debug session..." function in PL/SQL Developer from where I can type dbms_output.put_line to check on the variables, although still not ideal. But seems Oracle SQL Developer lack such capability

Comment: The scope of the debug session is such that what's happening in packageB has no meaning in packageA